# Pass Execution with tags - robot 3.2.2

Tags: robotframework

When using 'Pass Execution' message  tags in suite setup
tags are being set to all Test Cases
but those are not excluded if excluding this tag in robot command.

Any Idea about such issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "When using 'Pass Execution' message tags in suite setup tags are being set to all Test Cases" can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--exclude` command line option only works on tags that exist on a test case prior to the execution of the test.

Comment: Thanks, what is the use of these tag addition during run?

Comment: @YairShahar: for statistics